# Unexpected HTTP request mode while fetching font file from same origin

Tags: cors, service-worker, fetch-api

I am hosting a font from the same website that uses it (i.e. same origin) and I stumbled upon something strange while implementing my caching strategy inside the app's service worker.

Fetch requests for fonts (i.e. `request.destination === 'font'`) have a value of `'cors'` for their `mode` property, which is strange considering that the font is downloaded from the same origin it's being hosted.

#### Website structure

```
- /index.html
- /font.woff2
- /image.svg
- /sw.js
```

#### The issue

Locally-hosted font is requested by the app from the same origin but when the service worker intercepts the network request for the font, the underlying [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) has [mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) === `'cors'`, despite being served from the same origin.

#### HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Font cors test</title>

  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Comfortaa';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 300 700;
      font-display: swap;
      src: url('/Comfortaa-Variable.woff2') format('woff2-variations');
      unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
    }

    html {
      font-family: Comfortaa, sans-serif;
    }

    body {
      width: 100vw;
      position: relative;
      display: grid;
      place-content: center;
    }

    h1 {
      color: salmon;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

    <script>
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            window.addEventListener('load', () => {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
                    .catch( function ( err ) {
                        console.error('Failed to register service worker:', err.stack);
                    });
            });
        }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hi there!</h1>
  <img src="/patrick.svg" alt="Patrick Star">
</body>
</html>
```

#### Service worker code

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  console.debug('=============================================');
  console.debug('Service worker fetch request:');
  console.debug(event.request);
  console.debug('URL:', event.request.url);
  console.debug('DESTINATION:', event.request.destination);
  console.debug('MODE:', event.request.mode);
});
```

#### [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mzenz/font_cors)

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Visit [test site](https://font-cors-issue.netlify.app/).
2. Open console in dev tools.
3. Refresh page so that requests go through service worker (installed & activated in step 1).

#### Observed behavior

Two resources are fetched from the same origin, one image file, one font file:

- Image request has `mode === 'no-cors'` as expected.
- Font has `mode === 'cors'` despite being downloaded from the same origin.

I've been looking at the spec for [font fetching requirements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-fetching-requirements) but cannot see why this would be the case.

The reason I ask is because I've been using `Request.mode` to decide which assets to cache and which ones I should not and this issue breaks my caching heuristic, forcing me to give special treatment to fonts for no apparent reason.

Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: What the question describes is expected behavior. Where the CSS Fonts spec now has *“use the potentially CORS-enabled fetch method”*, what it really means is, *“create a potential-CORS request”* https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/urls-and-fetching.html#create-a-potential-cors-request, the first step of which is: *“Let mode be "no-cors" if corsAttributeState is No CORS, and "cors" otherwise”*. For font requests, *corsAttributeState* is Anonymous, and so the mode is "cors" — even if same-origin. (I raised https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/pull/5838 to fix the outdated spec language.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, good to know it's not a bug.

Comment: @martinzen, have you tested to see if this cors request makes your service worker think that it has an update? I have a feeling that this might be what causes an issue I have been having in Angular. A library is calling ```@font-face``` and shortly after that the service worker runs cache busting. Here's a reference to what I'm experiencing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71698453/angular-material-roboto-font-disrupting-service-worker